# setAutoresizingMask from code in osx

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, autoresizingmask

There is a section in size inspector with name Atosizing that can set left,right,up,down layout of a control,i find that i do that with `setAutoresizingMask` but don't know how set it that my control layout to right and up (means when user resize window my control steak to right and up)

Answer (score 12):

Look at these `-setAutoresizingMask` parameters:

> ***NSViewNotSizable***
>
> The receiver cannot be resized.
>
> ***NSViewMinXMargin***
>
> The left margin between the receiver and its superview is flexible.
>
> ***NSViewWidthSizable***
>
> The receiver’s width is flexible.
>
> ***NSViewMaxXMargin***
>
> The right margin between the receiver and its superview is flexible.
>
> ***NSViewMinYMargin***
>
> The bottom margin between the receiver and its superview is flexible.
>
> ***NSViewHeightSizable***
>
> The receiver’s height is flexible.
>
> ***NSViewMaxYMargin***
>
> The top margin between the receiver and its superview is flexible.

**So You can do it like this:**

```
[YourOutlet setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin];
```

Comment: so if i want to set my control fix to right and top i should use `[btn setAutoresizingMask: ~NSViewMaxXMargin & ~NSViewMinYMargin];` but with this code my control disappear and i change `&` to `|` but again my control disappear

Comment: @sZSzsZ try to remove ~. With Max and min You will fix to left. Try mine min min.

Comment: i test all of states (Min,Max,~,..) but my control doesn't fix

Comment: @sZSzsZ But with all states your control changes? or not? Maybe You forgot to Outlet *Btn*?

Comment: Then show my how You doing in code or create sample project and send me, I will check it.

Comment: `NSButton *btn=[[NSButton alloc]init];
btn.frame=CGRectMake(x+2, 0, 70, 70);
btn setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"AddUser"]];
[btn setAutoresizingMask: …];
[myView addSubview:btn];`

Comment: You adding button as Your custom View's subview so Your button moves how Your View can move, if You want to control Your button's autoresizing add to Window's view like this `[[windowOutlet contentView] addSubview:btn];`. (windowOutlet is Your main window *IBOutlet*)

Comment: i need to add it to a view (view that i add in code) what should i do now?

Comment: Hmm.. You can use `-setAutoresizesSubview` but I don't think that this will help You. So I suggest to create new View inside MainWindow's View with buttons size and autoresize it. It's hard to understand why You can't do it without NSView. **Or You can place Your button to right top corner of Your current View and enable resize to right and up and width sizable (ALL FOR VIEW) than it should work.** I can't imagine how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Hi guys i have got a problem 
I have some code that says "[_indicatorView setAutoresizingMask:63];"
Can you help me understand what this means.

Comment: @Taranmeet setting autoresizing mask to 63 means that all parameters are on. It's shorter than write every parameter in line.