# What's my best course of action for using UIScrollViews in my Storyboard when it's predominantly Auto Layout based?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I want to embed `UIScrollView`s in my `UITableViewCell`s in order to accomplish the iOS 7 cell sliding paradigm (seen in Mail.app among others).

I normally set up the entirety of my app in Storyboards and use Auto Layout. `UIScrollView` is unfortunately [very annoying to use in conjunction with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718265/is-it-possible-to-have-a-uiimageview-inside-of-a-uiscrollview-zoom-in-and-out-b), so I guess I'm going to have to avoid using it.

What's my best course of action for using `UIScrollView` with a Storyboard that uses Auto Layout? (I need the scroll view to adapt to a landscape orientation switch, something that would be very easy with Auto Layout.) I still would like to use Storyboards, and need to position the scroll views, but as I can't just switch to strings and struts for one view, and Auto Layout is out, I'm rather stuck.

Should I create its size in portrait, not set any constraints, and then in `viewDidLoad` set some auto-resizing masks? Or is it only zooming that `UIScrollView`s and Auto Layout conflict over, and simple panning should be fine?

Comment: I don't quite get your question you want to just slide the cell so you can see more options? And you are supporting both orientations?

If that's the case I would use UIViewAutoresizingMask

UIViewFlexibleWidth | UIViewFlexibleRightMargin

You probably might want copy paste your cell code to receive a adequate feedback

Comment: Why don't you use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/reproducing-the-ios-7-mail-apps-interface/ and an implementation using autolayout at https://github.com/Jafared/JASwipeCellExperiment.

Courtesy of jafar's comment on [Swipe to Delete and the "More" button (like in Mail app on iOS 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7).